# Getting Bean creation exception for batch job in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Getting exception can someone help me how to resolve it

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchConfigurerConfiguration$JpaBatchConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at com.optum.cams.adddocumentapi.AdddocumentapiApplication.main(AdddocumentapiApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:177) ~[spring-batch-core-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.createJobRepository(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:133) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.initialize(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:101) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(BasicBatchConfigurer.java:95) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
... 23 common frames omitted

```
My BatchConfig class

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class AdddocumentBatchConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdddocumentBatchConfig.class);

    private static final String QUERY_FIND_FAILEDDOCS = ""

    private static final String QUERY_UPDATE_FAILEDDOCS = "";

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public JpaConfig jpaConfig;

    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1)
                .end().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(DataSource dataSource, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<DocumentLogVO, DocumentLogVO>chunk(10).reader(jdbcCursorItemReader())
                .processor(processor()).writer(documentDatabaseItemWriter(dataSource, jdbcTemplate)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AddDocumentBatchRetry processor() {
        return new AddDocumentBatchRetry();
    }

    @Bean
    ItemWriter<DocumentLogVO> documentDatabaseItemWriter(DataSource dataSource,
            NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<DocumentLogVO> databaseItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        databaseItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        databaseItemWriter.setJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
        databaseItemWriter.setSql(QUERY_UPDATE_FAILEDDOCS);
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter<DocumentLogVO> documentPreparedStatementSetter = new DocumentPreparedStatementSetter();
        databaseItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(documentPreparedStatementSetter);

        return databaseItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader jdbcCursorItemReader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader personJdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        personJdbcCursorItemReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_FAILEDDOCS);
        personJdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(jpaConfig.dataSource());
        personJdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(DocumentLogVO.class));
        return personJdbcCursorItemReader;
    }

}
```

Comment: org/springframework/jdbc/support/lob/OracleLobHandler is undefined as a class. Maybe you need to import something.

Comment: It worked added an import import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler.Thank you Lajos

Comment: You are welcome. I have written an answer containing the solution to the problem you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that `OracleLobHandler` was not imported. The solution was to `import` it with this line

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.LobHandler.
```